# Authentication is not happening in spring security, directly going to the authenticated page

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security

My security xml is ::

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"  
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"   
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd  
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security  
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">  

    <security:http auto-config="true">
        <security:intercept-url method="POST" pattern="/admin**" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <security:http-basic />
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
      <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:user-service>
        <security:user name="user" password="pass" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </security:user-service>
      </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

</beans>
```

I am using spring-security 3.2.xsd. In this application it should prompt for login while accessing the /admin pages. But it is directly going to the /admin pages without the authentication.
Please specify me where i am wrong.

My dispatcher servlet :::

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.suva.*" />

    <bean
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
      </property>
      <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
      </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

My web.xml is::::

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

    <!-- Spring MVC -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

        <!-- Loads Spring Security config file -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
        </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name >
        <url-pattern>/**</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>

        </web-app>
```

My controller class ::

*

```
package com.suva.controller;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/welcome**" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView welcomePage() {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.addObject("title", "Spring Security Hello World");
        model.addObject("message", "This is welcome page!");
        model.setViewName("hello");
        return model;

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/admin**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView adminPage() {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.addObject("title", "Spring Security Hello World");
        model.addObject("message", "This is protected page!");
        model.setViewName("admin");

        return model;

    }

}
```

The JSP files::

hello.jsp ::

*

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@page session="false"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Title : ${title}</h1>   
    <h1>Message : ${message}</h1>   
</body>
</html>
```

*
admin.jsp

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@page session="true"%>
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Title : ${title}</h1> 
    <h1>Message : ${message}</h1> 

    <c:if test="${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name != null}">
       <h2>Welcome : ${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name} 
            <a href="<c:url value="/j_spring_security_logout" />" > Logout</a></h2>  
    </c:if>
</body>
</html>
```

Thats it nothing else.. please help me find out where i am wrong

Comment: What happens if you use pattern="/admin/**"?

Comment: sorry geoand for late reply.. but its same thing happening..

Comment: Can you please post the rest of your Spring configuration and also your web.xml

Comment: Also try dropping auto-config="true" and see what happens

Comment: i have edited the question with web.xml and dispatcher-servlet.xml

Comment: Check and see if adding /WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml to contextConfigLocation changes anything

Comment: if i remove auto-config= "true" then it will give me an exception:::

org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: No AuthenticationEntryPoint could be established. Please make sure you have a login mechanism configured through the namespace (such as form-login) or specify a custom AuthenticationEntryPoint with the 'entry-point-ref' attribute

actually i have no login page but the default login page should show in this scenario.

Comment: adding the  /WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml to contextConfigLocation is giving the below exception::

org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined

Comment: Weird things... Do you have your code on GitHub or something?

Comment: nopes but i can share my code snippets here...what codes do u need???

Comment: I don't have any more guesses as what might be wrong... The only way I can think of to help out is to build and run the code myself

Comment: @geoand :: i have pasted the class and jsp files here.. can u please tell me where i am wrong..

Comment: Are you using maven as a build tool?

Comment: nopes.. i am doing it from the eclipse only.. just needed some basic spring jars..i dont think its a build issue..u can do it also in maven..because the tutorial i am referring is using maven..

The website i am referring::
http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hello-world-example/

Comment: No problem, I will use that tutorial to see what happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be solved simply by changing the following in your web.xml

```
<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name >
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: yess it is working..Thank you geoand.. but can you tell me why is "/*" working but "/" or "/**" not working??

Comment: Your welcome! I don't really know the former works and latter does not, my knowledge is a little fuzzy on ant matchers